# How to create dynamic NSDictionary to store multiple URLs with multiple keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to store multiple urls with it's name , websitename and rssfeed url . 
How can I store it in dictionary ?

Like ,

My key is , `@"nameoffeed", @"websitename", @"urlfeedname"` I want to store all in dictionary related to url .
Like user search 3 feed then  name , websitename and urlfeed all are stored in NSDictionary ?

How can I do this ?

I am using this , but it stores only 1 value .

```
  //newdevice1 is my nsmanageobject
 NSArray *keys = [[[newDevice1 entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
                        NSDictionary *singledict = [newDevice1 dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

I need this type of result in dictionary.

```
{
    nameoffeed = "cnn" ;
    websitename = "www.cnn.com";
    urlfeedname = "www.cnn.com/feed";

     nameoffeed = "nytimes" ;
    websitename = "www.nytimes.com";
    urlfeedname = "www.nytimes.com/feed";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My key is , @"nameoffeed", @"websitename", @"urlfeedname" I want to
>   store all in dictionary related to url . Like user search 3 feed then
>   name , websitename and urlfeed all are stored in NSDictionary ?

Based on this, I believe you want a dictionary of dictionaries, where each sub-dictionary is indexed by the name.

In your example, you are already creating the dictionary for an individual object using `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys`.

All you need to do is add each one to a dictionary by the url key.

First, you need a mutable dictionary to add items to...

```
NSMutableDictionary *byURL = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then, for each item, grab the "url" you will use as a key...

```
NSString *name = [newDevice1 valueForKey:@"nameoffeed"];
```

and add the values to the dictionary

```
if (name) {
    NSArray *keys = [[[newDevice1 entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
    byURL[name] = [newDevice1 dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
}
```

You can then do the same thing for each object, resulting in a dictionary where you can look up each object by url.

```
NSDictionary *d = byURL[@"cnn"];
```

will give you the dictionary containing all the key/value pairs for "cnn"

If you want to end up with an immutable dictionary that is to be used strictly for searching (after adding everything you want to add), you can create an immutable copy...

```
NSDictionary *objectsByURL = [byURL copy];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do by this way.

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"nameoffeed":@"cnn",@"websitename":@"www.cnn.com",@"urlfeedname":@"www.cnn.com/feed"};
NSDictionary *dic2 = @{@"nameoffeed":@"nytimes",@"websitename":@"www.nytimes.com",@"urlfeedname":@"www.nytimes.com/feed"};
NSArray *dicArray = @[dic,dic2];
```

Comment: if any problem, fell free to ask

Answer (score 0):

In Dictionary we can save or store the multiple key values.But it must be the Different key.The Key name must not be the same.If use store the same key name in dictionary,it shows you error or your app crashes.But you can have the same values in dictionary.You have to store the different key name with multiple same values.

You can save the save the set of dictionaries to array like below

```
NSDictionary *dictFirstSet = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"cnn",@"nameoffeed",@"www.cnn.com",@"websitename",@"www.cnn.com/feed",@"urlfeedname",nil];
NSDictionary *dictSecondSet = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"nytimes",@"nameoffeed",@"www.nytimes.com",@"websitename",@"www.nytimes.com/feed",@"urlfeedname",nil];
NSArray *arrayDict = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dictFirstSet,dictSecondSet,nil];
NSLog(@"The arrayDict is - %@",arrayDict);
```

The output is

```
  The arrayDict is - (
    {
    nameoffeed = cnn;
    urlfeedname = "www.cnn.com/feed";
    websitename = "www.cnn.com";
},
    {
    nameoffeed = nytimes;
    urlfeedname = "www.nytimes.com/feed";
    websitename = "www.nytimes.com";
}
)
```